# Exclude records where count > 5 and select top 1 of it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to exclude records where id > 5 then select the top 1 of it order by date. How can I achieve this? Each record has audit_line which is unique field for each record. Recent SQL script is on below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table 
HAVING COUNT(id) > 5
```

Comment: `exclude records where id > 5 then select the top 1 of it` is a contradiction: you want to exclude or include these rows?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface If those records where id > 5. I want to include the top 1 of those 5 records order by date. So it will exclude the 4 records.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `id > 5` then you want `where`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from db.table t
where id > 5
order by date;
```

Comment: Hi This query will only fetch id > 5. Need a query to fetch where count(id) > 5. Then exclude the 4 records then get the top 1 record on it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use row-numbering for this.**

Note that if you have no other column to order by, you can do `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`, but then you may get different results on each run.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY some_other_column) rn
    FROM table
) t
WHERE rn = 5;
```